# Python Resize all images in a folder

Tags: python, performance, resize

I have the following code that I thought would resize the images in the specified path But when I run it, nothing works and yet python doesn't throw any error so I don't know what to do. Please advise. Thanks

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from PIL import Image
def image_resize(folder):
    images = []
    num_images = 0
    location = folder+"_"
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder, filename))
        if img is not None:
            new_img = np.array(Image.fromarray(img).resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS))  # Resize the images to 50 X 50
            images.append(new_img)
            num_images += 1
            cv2.imwrite("{}/{}".format(location, filename), new_img)
            return None

image_resize("2S1")
image_resize("SLICY")
image_resize("BRDM-2")
image_resize("BTR-60")
image_resize("D7")
image_resize("T62")
image_resize("ZIL131")
image_resize("ZSU-23_4")
```

all image in folder: G:\sar
help me

Answer (score 0):

It does not do anything because your for loop is not finding any files in the folder.  You are never passing the "G:\sar" part of the file path.

Comment: i write and
from PIL import Image   (folder="G:\\sar")   and  then write (for)  but no responsible

Comment: Place a print statement just inside your for loop to see if the loop is being executed